# Can I ask a regex question? I want it to be short.

Tags: discussion

I asked a regex question over at SO. Someone answered with a ruby solution. I'm pretty sure it can be done with GNU tools. I remembered seeing all the cool things here when snooping around area51. Is it alright to ask that question here?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956635/regex-awk-etc-for-scanning-my-source-code-for-translations

Comment: Someone else helped out nicely. I'm still interested in shorter versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My point of view is you shouldn't be asking here because you're trying to get help. You *should* ask here if you know the problem presents a interesting challenge in some way.

This will be very hard to police: we're basically relying on you to police yourself.

Of course, there must exist the corner case, and I'd say "on-topic" for those.

Comment: I see. That makes sense considering the nature of this site.